# Track collection in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling, traffic-simulation

I'm building a pedestrian model using Anylogic. I have set my agents move in several groups between S2/S3/S4 and S1 (the movement direction is indicated by the blue two-way arrow in the figure). [Background picture for problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBUP6.png)

I have build a cyclic event and type these code in "action" to collect their track data:

```
t = time();    //get time
for(Agent p: level.getPeds()){
        x = p.getX();    //position x
        y = p.getY();    //Position y
        id = p.getId();    //get pedestrian id
        collectionTime.add(t);    //add data
        collectionID.add(id);
        collectionX.add(x);
        collectionY.add(y);
        Timeid.add(t,id);
        XY.add(x,y);
}
```

I also add these code in "Main-Agent type_Agent actions_On destroy" to write data into excel file:

```
TrackCollection.writeDataSet(Timeid,1,1,1);    //TrackCollection is the name of excel file
TrackCollection.writeDataSet(XY,1,1,3);
```

But in this way I can only collect all the trajectories together in the model. How can I collect the tracks of these different groups separately? Or how to collect tracks from different PedSources?

Comment: can you clarify the code, this is not actual correct syntax. Also, what are TrackCollections?

Comment: Thanks so much, Benjamin, for comments. I have edited my question and clarify the code. The current question is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, nevertheless, if you are creating groups, you can do this after creating a groupId variable in your pedestrian agent.

```
for(Pedestrian p : group.getPeds()){
    p.groupId=group.getId();
}
```

you can use this groupId and export it to your excel too so you can keep track of the groups